# how to create a form generator from json object using js

Tags: javascript, json

[image]

how to make text at the same line of another With JSON object for example: TEXT:Input text, and a submit button that if i write a value inside the input text it automatically write the values for the other input text how can i do it that was really hard for me to figure it out and i did a research about it but i didnt find anything so can you help.

```js
const objs = [{ "Object1": { "ID": 1, "type": "input", "color": "red", "Text": "DARKDRAGON", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "15px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object2": { "ID": 2, "type": "textarea", "color": "cyan", "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "70px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object3": { "ID": 3, "type": "input", "color": "blue", "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "130px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object4": { "ID": 4, "type": "button", "color": "darkorange", "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "190px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } } }]


Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {

  const formItem = objs[0][key];
  const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
  if (formItem.type === "button") elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
  else elmn.value = formItem.Text;
  Object.assign(elmn.style, {
    position: 'absolute',
    color: formItem.color,
    width: formItem.width,
    height: formItem.height,
    top: formItem.top,
    left: formItem.left,
    fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
    fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
  });

  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
});
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea"></div>
```

how to make text at the same line of another With JSON object for example: TEXT:Input text, and a submit button that if i write a value inside the input text it automatically write the values for the other input text how can i do it that was really hard for me to figure it out and i did a research about it but i didnt find anything so can you help.

Comment: all i want is to make a input text that like when i press the submit button it puts a value for all the objects

Comment: if u didn't understand i will try my best to explain

Comment: want more explanation please ask

Comment: by just using (json and Js)

Comment: @mplungjan i did what u want i edited it and there are more info

Comment: @mplungjan u there?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl u here?

Comment: Take it easy. I have a life too

Comment: srry but i need it soo bad

Comment: So show the expected html output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219919/discussion-between-speedytiger2161-and-mplungjan).

Comment: the picture up describes what i want but in my json object

Comment: Please change the object to reflect the form elements. You have nothing like payment Terms in the object you have now.

Comment: but this picture is like an example

Comment: i dont want it payment terms and our Refrence i want it (Name) and (Value)

Comment: like something like that https://jsfiddle.net/crnbgfj3/ . but i want some name above them says like(NAME:) then beside it (value) but i want it above them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/otbgvzp8/

```js
const objs = [{ "Object1": { "ID": 1, "type": "input", "color": "red", "Text": "DARKDRAGON", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "15px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object2": { "ID": 2, "type": "textarea", "color": "cyan", "Text": "SPEEDYTIGER", "width": "150px", "height": "40px", "top": "70px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object3": { "ID": 3, "type": "input", "color": "blue", "Text": "AMyesteriousAdults", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "130px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } }, "Object4": { "ID": 4, "type": "button", "color": "darkorange", "Text": "AMyesteriousDarkSpeed", "width": "200px", "height": "40px", "top": "190px", "left": "5px", "Font": { "fontName": "tahoma", "font": "17px" } } }];

const breakFlex = document.createElement("p");
breakFlex.style.flexBasis = "100%";
breakFlex.style.height= 0;

Object.keys(objs[0]).forEach(key => {

  const formItem = objs[0][key];
  const elmn = document.createElement(formItem.type);
  if (formItem.type === "button")
    elmn.innerHTML = formItem.Text;
  else
    elmn.placeholder = formItem.Text;
  Object.assign(elmn.style, {
    color: formItem.color,
    width: formItem.width,
    height: formItem.height,
    top: formItem.top,
    left: formItem.left,
    fontFamily: formItem.Font.fontName,
    fontSize: formItem.Font.font,
    flex: '1 0 45%',
  });
  if (formItem.type !== "button") {
    const label = document.createElement("label");
    label.innerHTML = formItem.Text + "<br/>";
    label.style.fontSize="smaller";
    label.appendChild(elmn);
    document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(label);
  } else document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(elmn);
  document.getElementById('ColorArea').appendChild(breakFlex.cloneNode());
});
```

```html
<div id="ColorArea" style='display:flex;flex-wrap: wrap'>

</div>
```

Comment: PS: No need for `breakFlex.classList.add("break")` now

Comment: why cant i change the width of this button ? is cuz i didn't put the css?

Comment: It is flex. You have added `flex: '1 0 45%',` to all elements. Remove or change that for the button

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is an example, I have modified your JSON object so you can add more styles and types... i don't know if this is what you want...

```js
var inputs = [
  {
    "ID": "inp1",
    "Element": "input",
    "Type": "text",
    "Text": "your name",
    "Styles": {
      "font-family": "tahoma",
      "font-size": "17px"
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "inp5",
    "Element": "input",
    "Type": "number",
    "Text": "your age",
    "Styles": {
      "font-family": "tahoma",
      "font-size": "17px",
      "color": "yellow",
      "background": "blue" 
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": "inp16",
    "Element": "input",
    "Type": "password",
    "Text": "put your password",
    "Styles": {
      "font-family": "tahoma",
      "font-size": "17px",
      "color": "blue",
      "background": "yellow" 
    }
  }
];

function createForm(someInputs) {
  var newForm = document.createElement("form");
  someInputs.forEach(function(input) {
    var styles = "";
    Object.keys(input.Styles).forEach(function(key) {
      styles += `${key}: ${input.Styles[key]};`;
    });
    newForm.innerHTML += `<${input.Element} type="${input.Type}" id="${input.Id}" placeholder="${input.Text}" style="${styles}"><br>`;
  });
  document.body.appendChild(newForm);
}

createForm(inputs);
```